# Datapower to handle all the business (no backend server)

Tags: ibm-datapower

According to IBM XML-FW is there only for testing and debugging, what Im looking for is a way to let the Datapower do all the business with no backend server.

so basically i need to configure a MPG to read from the database and send the result back to the client **with no backend server to be involed.**

**what is the practice to accomplish this without using XML FW loop-back?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this within any rules in a MPG, by simply switching the "skip-backside" flag to true. The behavior is the same as a XML FW loop-back... any transformation will do.

The precise variable is var://service/mpgw/skip-backside when used in XSLT... you can obviously use it in GatewayScript as well.

By setting this variable to 1, you essentially turn any rule into a "loop-back".

Here is [one of the references I found on the subject](http://datapowerfresher.blogspot.com/2015/05/creating-loopback-service-on-mpg.html).